# Take picture with iPhone API and transfer it to a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, data-transfer

I have written an cocoa application to take a picture on the iPhone.  I need to transfer the images taken to somewhere besides the iPhone namely another server.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: hey, what class did u use for taking the picture ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First get a server and figure out what kind of phone <---> server API you want to use.  There are any number of ways it can work.  A simple and common scheme is a REST API with photos being uploaded via HTTP POST.

The basic scheme would be something like:

1. Take picture
2. Convert to JPG (there's a function for this)
3. Construct HTTP POST using the NSURL* classes
4. Set JPG data as POST body (or one part of a mutipart form post)

Converting to base64 should not be necessary.

If you've never put together any kind of server API, there are any number of examples available.  Most photo-sharing sites have public APIs which may be useful references.

Answer (score 4):

By far the easiest way is to use an HTTP `POST`. Take a look at the "URL Loading System" in your documentation and then examine the related classes, particularly `NSURLRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

As other people say, use HTTP POST. [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) makes wrapping your POST up simple. It also moves your upload to a background thread and gives your delegate progress updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could always convert the image data to a base 64 string and POST it to a php (or other) script on the target server.