# how to send and receive files from server in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, file, ftp

How to send and reveice files from a ftp server ?

If any sample project or example is there ,then its easy to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search is your friend.

Here are some:

[Upload File to FTP Server on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone)
[Uploading and downloading via ftp with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk)
[Upload photo to arbitrary FTP with iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128378/upload-photo-to-arbitrary-ftp-with-iphone-app)
[Take picture with iPhone API and transfer it to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699529/take-picture-with-iphone-api-and-transfer-it-to-a-server)
[IPhone - Get file last modified date from web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380781/iphone-get-file-last-modified-date-from-web-server)
[File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)
[how send file (txt/XML) from iphone to server(web or email)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130969/how-send-file-txt-xml-from-iphone-to-serverweb-or-email)